# Why does the order of my array keep change while in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I am running the following code (which I appreciate has some duplication and needs tidying up):

```
async function translateRequests(nameOfRequestsArray) {
  document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
  for (let i = 0; i < nameOfRequestsArray.length; i++) {
    //see if nameOfRequestsArray[i] has been translated already and if it has then skip it!
    if (nameOfRequestsArray[i].lastUpdated.length != 3) {
    //translate requesters
    let a = users.map(function(search) { return search.id; }).indexOf(nameOfRequestsArray[i].requester);
    nameOfRequestsArray[i].requesterFirstName = users[a].firstName;
    nameOfRequestsArray[i].requesterSurname = users[a].surname;
    //translate requestees
    console.log(nameOfRequestsArray[i]);
    console.log('i1: ' + i);
    if (nameOfRequestsArray[i].type == 'user') {
      let b = users.map(function(search) { return search.id; }).indexOf(nameOfRequestsArray[i].requestee);
      nameOfRequestsArray[i].requesteeFirstName = users[b].firstName;
      nameOfRequestsArray[i].requesteeSurname = users[b].surname;
    } else if (nameOfRequestsArray[i].type == 'team') {
      //get teams if they haven't already been downloaded
      if (teams.length == 0) {
        //get teams
        data = JSON.stringify({"active": true});
        teams = await makeRequest("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:7071/retrieveteams", data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(teams), nameOfRequestsArray[i].requestee)
      }
      console.log(nameOfRequestsArray[i]);
      console.log('i2: ' + i);
      let d = teams.map(function(search) { return search.id; }).indexOf(nameOfRequestsArray[i].requestee);
      nameOfRequestsArray[i].requesteeFirstName = teams[d].teamName;
    }
    //translate categories
    let c = categories.map(function(search) { return search.id; }).indexOf(nameOfRequestsArray[i].categoryId);
    nameOfRequestsArray[i].categoryName = categories[c].name;
    //split up lastUpdated dates
    let z = Date.parse(nameOfRequestsArray[i].lastUpdated) - timezoneOffset;
    z = new Date(z).toISOString();
    nameOfRequestsArray[i].lastUpdated = z.replace('Z','').split('T');
    nameOfRequestsArray[i].lastUpdated[2] = nameOfRequestsArray[i].lastUpdated[0].split('-').reverse().join('-');
    z = nameOfRequestsArray[i].lastUpdated[2].split('-');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('01','Jan');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('02','Feb');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('03','Mar');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('04','Apr');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('05','May');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('06','Jun');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('07','Jul');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('08','Aug');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('09','Sep');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('10','Oct');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('11','Nov');
    z[1] = z[1].replace('12','Dec');
    nameOfRequestsArray[i].lastUpdated[2] = z.join('-');
    //translate updates
    for (let x in nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates) {
      let d = users.map(function(search) { return search.id; }).indexOf(nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates[x].author);
      nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates[x].authorFirstName = users[d].firstName;
      nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates[x].authorSurname = users[d].surname;
      //translate the update dates
      let y = Date.parse(nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates[x].date) - timezoneOffset;
      y = new Date(y).toISOString();
      nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates[x].date = y.replace('Z','').split('T');
      nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates[x].date[0] = nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates[x].date[0].split('-').reverse().join('-');
      y = nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates[x].date[0].split('-');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('01','Jan');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('02','Feb');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('03','Mar');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('04','Apr');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('05','May');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('06','Jun');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('07','Jul');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('08','Aug');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('09','Sep');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('10','Oct');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('11','Nov');
      y[1] = y[1].replace('12','Dec');
      nameOfRequestsArray[i].updates[x].date[2] = y.join('-');
    }
    }
  }
  document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
}
```

This outputs the following in the console:

```
{type: "team", requester: "2f3e7466-28c7-1c90-cfaf-3dc8370d5dd3", requestee: "88edea02-f145-d79f-f077-e2b6a5db8972", categoryId: "2cb42736-f243-dacb-9961-9e007dc51f29", priority: 1, …}
javascript.js:135 i1: 26
javascript.js:208 type: undefined
javascript.js:146 [{"teamName":"Alpha 1","id":"88edea02-f145-d79f-f077-e2b6a5db8972"}] 2f3e7466-28c7-1c90-cfaf-3dc8370d5dd3
javascript.js:148 {type: "user", requester: "2f3e7466-28c7-1c90-cfaf-3dc8370d5dd3", requestee: "2f3e7466-28c7-1c90-cfaf-3dc8370d5dd3", categoryId: "2cb42736-f243-dacb-9961-9e007dc51f29", priority: 2, …}
javascript.js:149 i2: 26
```

As you can see (see the requestee and priority properties), when it gets to nameOfRequestsArray[26] it appears that the order of the array is changing, even though i still = 26. I thought the point of an array was that unless your explicitly change order by doing a .sort or .reverse, the data inside stays in the same order? This is causing execution issues that I've not experienced before.

Comment: Where is `translateRequests` called, where does its argument come from? Given that you have an `await` in your code, maybe somewhere else in your code you are changing the same array.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can test your code, and so that any code unrelated to the problem is not bogging down the question.

Comment: Ah! It was the calling function not waiting for translateRequests to complete before running my sorting function! A simple await fixed this issue and my previous issue! I'll pop it in as an answer for reference and to avoid confusing anyone else in a similar situation

Answer (score 0):

As translateRequests is an async function, the function calling it should use await it's completion before the next function is called (in my case, one that was sorting the array) which is why the arrays contents shifted around